# How to insert autogenerated ID in two columns in JPA/JAVA/Hibernate

Tags: java, jpa

I Generate id with autogenerator in JPA java in DAO class. 
Because of the silly database architecture I need to generate the primary key and insert same id into two columns in same table

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = DataConstants.ABC)
@Column(name = "SYS_ID")
private Long Sysid;

@Column(name = "SYS_NUM")
private Long sysNum;
```

Right now I have the DAO class as above which works fine and insert auto generated primary key in SYS_ID column.

One way to solve this is insert the data and get the sysid and then run Update on it which doesn;t seem feasible to me.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why doesn't it seem feasible? Have you tried doing it? Where's the code you tried? What did you expect to happen and what happened instead?

Comment: Feasible in the sense I have to create two DB calls. we have users in millions so I am trying to figure out solution which gets the work done in one DB call

Comment: No. It depends on what your generator does. If it's sequence or table based, persisting the entity will not actually insert a row in the database. But it will assign a value to its ID. Check your assumptions by testing and observing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered a similar problem and eventually came up with the following solution: I use hibernate, panache, lombok for discription my entities:

Master.java

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@Table(name = "MASTER")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Master extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MASTERID", nullable = false)
    Long masterId;

    @Column(name = "DETAILID", nullable = false)
    Long detailId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "master", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    Set<Detail> details = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Column(name = "DATECREATED", nullable = false)
    Date dateCreated;

    public static Master createMasterWithLoadId() {
        Query nativeQuery = Panache.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery("select MASTER_SEQ.nextval from dual");
        Master master = new Master();
        master.masterId = id;
        master.detailId = id;
        return master;
    }

     @PrePersist
     public void prePersist() {
        if (dateCreated == null) {
           dateCreated = clearTime(Calendar.getInstance()).getTime();
        }
     }

     private Calendar clearTime(Calendar cal) {
         cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
         cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
         return cal;
     }
}
```

Detail.java

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RegisterForReflection
@IdClass(BatchContent.ContentId.class)
@Table(name = "DETAIL")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
public class Detail extends PanacheEntityBase {
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "detailId", nullable = false)
    Master master;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "one")
    Long one;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "two")
    Long two;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @RegisterForReflection
    @FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
    static class DetailId implements Serializable {

        Master master;

        Long one;

        Long two;

    }
}
```

use:

```
Master master = Master.createMasterWithLoadId();
for (RequestDetail rDet : rDetails) {
    master.details.add(new Detail(master, rDet.getOne(), rDet.getTwo()));
}
master.persist();
```